# show joomla article based on user's location

Tags: joomla, gps, location, article

I have joomla articles, each with latitude and longitude numbers (each article represents an adress).

I want to show articles based on the user's location, so if he uses the website through his smart phone, computer or tablet it should show the articles within a certain radius.

Is there a specific plugin which enables me to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Prastow

Answer (score 0):

Prastow, I don't think you will get an build-in extension which works exactly as per your requirement.
If you are Joomla developer you can do this easily. Just get the latitude and longitude of the user using google api & check the same that is stored in your Joomla database #__conent table. Show the matched article to the user. 
You can either create a new view or override existing com_content view. I think this won't take more than 3 hrs of basic coding.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I guess you are right. But I have difficulty understanding how to get the latitude and longitude. Doesn't this differ per system? (ios, android, pc?) And what if GPS is not turned on, is it possible to track the signal of the phone?

Maybe I'm thinking too difficult, but there is so many different hardware.